# Oracle Check Constraint

Tags: oracle, constraints

I've been struggling with this check constraint for a few hours and was hoping someone would be kind enough to explain why this check constraint isn't doing what I think it should be doing.

```
ALTER TABLE CLIENTS
add CONSTRAINT CHK_DISABILITY_INCOME_TYPE_ID CHECK ((IS_DISABLED IS NULL AND DISABILITY_INCOME_TYPE_ID IS NULL) OR (IS_DISABLED = 0 AND DISABILITY_INCOME_TYPE_ID IS NULL) OR (IS_DISABLED = 1));
```

Essentially, you must be disabled to collect disability income.  It appears as though the first part of this check constraint `(IS_DISABLED IS NULL AND DISABILITY_INCOME_TYPE_ID IS NULL)` is not enforced (see below).

The available values for `DISABILITY_INCOME_TYPE_ID` are 1 and 2, which is enforced via foreign key.  Both `IS_DISABLED` and `DISABILITY_INCOME_TYPE_ID` can be null.

```
-- incorrectly succeeds (Why?)
INSERT INTO CLIENTS (IS_DISABLED, DISABILITY_INCOME_TYPE_ID) VALUES (null, 1);
INSERT INTO CLIENTS (IS_DISABLED, DISABILITY_INCOME_TYPE_ID) VALUES (null, 2);

-- correctly fails
INSERT INTO CLIENTS (IS_DISABLED, DISABILITY_INCOME_TYPE_ID) VALUES (0, 1);
INSERT INTO CLIENTS (IS_DISABLED, DISABILITY_INCOME_TYPE_ID) VALUES (0, 2);

-- correctly succeeds
INSERT INTO CLIENTS (IS_DISABLED, DISABILITY_INCOME_TYPE_ID) VALUES (0, null);
INSERT INTO CLIENTS (IS_DISABLED, DISABILITY_INCOME_TYPE_ID) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO CLIENTS (IS_DISABLED, DISABILITY_INCOME_TYPE_ID) VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO CLIENTS (IS_DISABLED, DISABILITY_INCOME_TYPE_ID) VALUES (1, null);
INSERT INTO CLIENTS (IS_DISABLED, DISABILITY_INCOME_TYPE_ID) VALUES (null, null);
```

Thanks for your help,
Michael

Comment: Just verifying that I see the same behavior you're seeing on Oracle 10.2.0.4.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I do not have Oracle, I did a quick test with PostgreSQL and your first example (`IS_DISABLED` being `NULL` and `DISABILITY_INCOME_TYPE_ID` being 1):

```
postgres=> select (null is null and 1 is null);
 ?column?
----------
 f
(1 registro)

postgres=> select (null is null and 1 is null) or (null = 0 and 1 is null);
 ?column?
----------
 f
(1 registro)

postgres=> select (null is null and 1 is null) or (null = 0 and 1 is null) or (null = 1);
 ?column?
----------

(1 registro)
```

Here we see clearly that, in this case, your expression (at least on PostgreSQL) returns NULL. From [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/sql-createtable.html),

> [...] Expressions evaluating to TRUE or UNKNOWN succeed. Should any row of an insert or update operation produce a FALSE result an error exception is raised and the insert or update does not alter the database. [...]

So, if Oracle behaves the same as PostgreSQL, the check constraint would *pass*.

To see if this is the case, avoid the NULL shenanigans by explicily checking for it and see if it works:

```
CHECK ((IS_DISABLED IS NULL AND DISABILITY_INCOME_TYPE_ID IS NULL)
    OR (IS_DISABLED IS NOT NULL AND IS_DISABLED = 0 AND DISABILITY_INCOME_TYPE_ID IS NULL)
    OR (IS_DISABLED IS NOT NULL AND IS_DISABLED = 1));
```

Comment: I'm not sure your answer is correct yet, but your explanation was extremely helpful in me solving this problem on my own.  This whole time I was evaluation null = 1 as false, when in fact Oracle and Postgres evaluate this expression as unknown.  Major difference.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [NVL](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions110.htm#SQLRF00684) in the check condition.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why the compound check isn't working, but this works:

```
ALTER TABLE CLIENTS ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_1 CHECK (IS_DISABLED = 0 AND DISABILITY_INCOME_TYPE_ID IS NULL)

ALTER TABLE CLIENTS ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_2 CHECK (IS_DISABLED IS NULL AND DISABILITY_INCOME_TYPE_ID IS NULL)

ALTER TABLE CLIENTS ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_3 CHECK (IS_DISABLED = 1)
```

Regards
K

Answer (score 0):

This solution works.

```
CHECK
((IS_DISABLED IS NULL AND NVL(DISABILITY_INCOME_TYPE_ID, 0) = 0)
OR (IS_DISABLED = 0 AND NVL(DISABILITY_INCOME_TYPE_ID, 0) = 0) 
OR (IS_DISABLED IS NOT NULL AND IS_DISABLED = 1));
```