# Check Constraints

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I've been working on creating a table consisting of this...

1. Module(ModuleID, ModuleTitle, ModuleLeader, Credits,
   CourseworkPercentage, ExamPercentage)
2. ModuleID should be generated by a sequence
3. ModuleTitle and ModuleLeader should have at most 30 characters and
   should be not null
4. Credits should be not null and be 10, 20 or 40
5. CourseworkPercentage and ExamPercentage should add up to 100

I have successfully done points 2,3,5 but I am having problems with 4. Not sure how I could write a check constraint to say it has to equal to either 10,20 or 40.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
CHECK( Credits IS NOT NULL AND Credits IN ( 10,20,40))
```

NOT NULL condition is redundant - a column must be 10,20 or 40, all of them are not NULL, and the condition can be simplified into just:

```
CHECK( Credits IN ( 10,20,40) )
```

Answer (score 0):

It first looks like checking for NULL would be redundant, but I recently came across another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291493/oracle-check-constraint) which asks to have re-look at the [manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm)

> [...]A check constraint lets you specify a condition that each row in the table must satisfy. To satisfy the constraint, each row in the table must make the condition either TRUE or unknown (due to a null).[...]

So I suggest you better user

```
CHECK( Credits IS NOT NULL AND Credits IN ( 10,20,40))
```